# I am using axios post request for sending data from react to express, why data saves in response configs not in data?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am using axios post request for sending data from react to express, why data saves in response configs not in data?

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code from your express layer ?

Comment: server.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mailer = require('./SendMail');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});
app.use('/', mailer);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;




app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));

Comment: sendMail.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.post('/test',(req, res)=> {
     res.json(req.body );
});


 module.exports = router;

Comment: Please edit your original question with the additional code :)